# Qt: Detect system locale when language pack is installed

Tags: windows, macos, qt, localization, internationalization

I want to get system locale in Windows when language pack is installed.
For example, my actual OS locale is en_US, but I have installed pt_BR language pack. When I am using `QString sysLocale = QLocale::system().name();` it is giving me en-US and not pt-BR.

How do I get current UI system locale? Also how to do it in **Mac OSX** when we change Language through System Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

The locale which is set for the current Qt process should be available through

```
QLocale QApplication::keyboardInputLocale()
```

Comment: In Windows when you install a language pack, you can still choose to have keyboard input in other language. In my case, my original OS locale is en-US and I installed language pack for pt-BR, but I have chosen keyboard to take input in EN, although the Windows UI like Start Menu items, etc come in Portuguese (pt). Also I am using Qt 5.2 and it is not available in that.

Comment: basically you want to know which system locales are installed?

Comment: I want to know what the current UI locale is.